# What is the name of this mono spaced font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, monospace

I found this font really cool. Can someone tell me its name!

Here is an image:[image]

Comment: Hi AndrewMk. We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information, thanks!

Comment: Also, that font is obviously not monospaced. Otherwise, the letters from the different lines would have to be exactly below one another.

Answer (score 2):

The font you are looking for is:

Raleway Extra Bold (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway):

[image]